# Python loop in Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, loops

This is my nested functions code

```
   def get_id():
        for i in range(1,100):
            pass
            return i
    def get_id_mysql(x):
        print(x)
    
    
    variable = get_id()
    get_id_mysql(variable)
```

this function `get_id` return ( output : 1 ) and loop stop.. how can I hand over full loop? I mean 1,2,3..99

Comment: `return` terminates the function.

Answer (score 0):

I Found solutions

```
def get_id():
    t = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        t.append(i)
    return t
def get_id_mysql(x):
    for i in x:
        print(i)


variable = get_id()
get_id_mysql(variable)
```

Comment: In this example, `get_id` does not need to exist at all, just `get_id_mysql(range(1, 100))`. You can learn about [What are iterator, iterable, and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)

Comment: to add to what @MechanicPig said, you can also use list comprehension `[i for i in range(1, 100)]`